# How to align content by using grid css

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to align to use grid in my css to align a button and other element in the my page web.

I want to line up three side by side headings then the button at the bottom space from three headings at the top by 8 px and center the button. Then leave a margin between the button and the two divs containing the bottom messges as described in this image.

[image]

But I can't do it with this code. I want to use the css technique of grids with the titles in column grids and the buttons and the two message divs in line grids

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h4>Title 1</h4>
    <h4>Title 2</h4>
    <h4>Title 3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <button>List of messages</button>
    <div class="grid-item item">Message 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item item">Message 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: as requested I moved the tiles to a separate div. Both containers follow a 3 column layout.

To create 3 equally sized columns you can use `repeat(3, 1fr)` as value for the `grid-template-columns` property. The syntax is for `repeat` is:

```
amount, width/size
```

`1fr` (1 fraction) will give every column the same width while it equally distribute all available space to every single fraction. Means with 3 total fractions every fraction has to be 1/3 of the available space.

To align the button in the center column you can use `grid-column: 2 / 3;` which will start at grid-column-line 2 (between 1st and 2nd column) and end at grid-column-line 3 (between 2nd and 3rd column).

Then to add the margin to the button you simply add the margin to the button directly. I removed the default margin from the tile with `h4 { margin: 0; }`.

To have the text span the entire width available I used `grid-column: 1 / -1;` which will start at the first column and end after the last. You should not use `span 3` as value as the content needs to specifically start at the first line and not after the button.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.grid-container > h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container > .grid-item > button {
  margin: 8px 0 16px 0;  
  width: min-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-container > .grid-item {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <h4>Title 1</h4>
  <h4>Title 2</h4>
  <h4>Title 3</h4>
</div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item center"><button>List of messages</button></div>
  <div class="grid-item item">Message 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item item">Message 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @tacoshi, Yes it is. But is there any way to put the titles in a separate div from the others. Can you explain me what you have done

Comment: Hi @tacoshy I want the button to be aligned on the middle of the width of 3 titles and not that it starts on button 2. Look at the image on the post

Comment: you can give the button a certain width and center it within the column just fine.

Comment: Hi @tacoshy, You can modify your code by adding the width and center it so that I can see please. Is it possible to center it differently without giving a certain width, because I don't want to give a certain width so that it is responsive